# Displaying a card or table as a response in ibm watson assistant

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have created an IBM Watson Assistant dialog skill. When triggered, I require a node to display information in a card-like format. How can I achieve this?

Since I could not think of a way to create a card I tried displaying a table using HTML styling but the desired styling didn't reflect when tested in the 'try it' panel

Comment: Watson Assistant has the "Try it out" to test a dialog directly when building it. It has integrations with Slack / Facebook / ZenDesk and others and you can use it on websites or in your app. Where do you want to display it?

Comment: Later when my dialog is built I plan to integrate it with a certain app. It's not a general Facebook like app. I don't have a lot of details regarding the app. Is the solution dependent on the platform I integrate my chatbot with? If so, does that mean the output format will not be reflected in the 'try it out' even after I correct my code?

Comment: Correct, it depends on the target. See here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-native

Comment: You may wish to create and connect a preview assistant to your Watson dialog skill. This may display your html (cannot guarantee this, but may be worth a try). See here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-assistants
and
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-link